# How can I use integers as parameters for \ifcase

Tags: environments, ifthenelse

I am very confused about LaTeX's calculatation. I tried to defined an environment which could change its typography through an integer parameter I give freely. I chose `\ifcase` and tried as below:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{numexm}[section]
\setcounter{numexm}{0}
\renewcommand\thenumexm{\roman{numexm}}

%\newcounter{first}
%\setcounter{first}{1}

\newenvironment{ntexmC}[5][0]{
    \newcommand\makechoice{%
        \ifcase\value{#1}%
        \relax\or %
        A. #2 \hfill B. #3 \hfill
        C. #4 \hfill D. #5\or %
        A. #2\hspace{\stretch{2}} B. #3\hspace{\stretch{3}}\par
        C. #4\hspace{\stretch{2}} D. #5\hspace{\stretch{3}}\or %
        A. #2\par B. #3\par C. #4\par D. #5\else %
        \relax \fi
    }%
    \addvspace{.2em}\stepcounter{numexm}
    \setlength\parindent{0em} Example \thenumexm. 
}{\par\makechoice\addvspace{.2em}}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{ntexmC}[1]{AAAAAAA}{BBBBBBB}{CCCCCCC}{DDDDDDD}% replace 1 with first
    The title (\hspace{1em})
\end{ntexmC}

\end{document}
```

After I compiled it with `pdflatex`, an errors appeared:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

So I tried to use another counter to represent the integer. I defined `first` and set it to `1`(commented in the above ), then I replaced the first parameter with the counter. Another errors appears:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

However, the output is what I expect.

So the first question is if I can directly use an integer to switch the options like the first example?

And the second question is what was wrong with the second attempt?

If there are other tools can realize what I expect, it would be very nice of you if you can tell me by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ifcase <num> ... \fi` expects an integer for `<num>`. If you pass an integer, use it as-is, not as `\value{#1}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{numexm}[section]
\setcounter{numexm}{0}
\renewcommand\thenumexm{\roman{numexm}}

\newenvironment{ntexmC}[5][0]{
  \newcommand\makechoice{%
    \ifcase#1%
      \relax\or % 0
      A. #2 \hfill B. #3 \hfill C. #4 \hfill D. #5\or % 1
      A. #2\hspace{\stretch{2}} B. #3\hspace{\stretch{3}}\par
      C. #4\hspace{\stretch{2}} D. #5\hspace{\stretch{3}}\or % 2
      A. #2\par B. #3\par C. #4\par D. #5\else % 3
      \relax % 4
    \fi
  }%
  \addvspace{.2em}\stepcounter{numexm}
  \setlength\parindent{0em} Example \thenumexm. 
}{\par\makechoice\par\addvspace{.2em}}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{ntexmC}[1]{AAAAAAA}{BBBBBBB}{CCCCCCC}{DDDDDDD}% replace 1 with first
  The title (\hspace{1em})
\end{ntexmC}

\end{document}
```

`\addvspace{<len>}` requires to be in vertical mode, so precede it with `\par`. Here's the definition of `\addvspace` to show that an "no item error" will be thrown if not in `v`ertical `mode`:

```
\def\addvspace#1{%
  \ifvmode
     \if@minipage\else
       \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
         \@vspace@calcify{#1}%
       \else
       \setlength\@tempskipb{#1}%
         \@xaddvskip
       \fi
     \fi
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}
```

Answer (score 5):

The *only* legal construction involving `\value` is of the form

```
\value{<counter name>}
```

and it returns the “abstract” value of the integer stored in a counter.

You can use `\value{section}` or `\value{page}` in the context of `\ifcase` (or any defined counter). So you could do

```
\newcounter{forifcase}
\newenvironment{ntexmC}[5][0]{%
    \setcounter{forifcase}{#1}%
    \newcommand\makechoice{%
        \ifcase\value{forifcase}%
```

but it's much simpler to do

```
\newenvironment{ntexmC}[5][0]{%
    \newcommand\makechoice{%
        \ifcase#1\relax\or
```

The `\relax` will stop TeX from looking for more digits.